# Is the set $A=\{\frac1n,n\in\mathbb N\}$ bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am studying the following set

$$
A=\left\{\frac{1}{n},n\in \mathbb N\right\}
$$

Where $\mathbb N$ begins from $1$ not $0$. I know that the upper bound of this series is $1$ but what is the lower pound? Is it $0$ but $0$ doesn't exist in $N$ because $N=(0,1]$.

Does the lower/upper bound have to exist in the set. What I mean is can I pick for example $2$ to be the upper bound or $-2$ to be the lower bound?

Finally, is there an examples of (1) a set that is bounded from one end only and (2) an example of a set that is not bound from both ends?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Define what bounded means to you.

Comment: You have several questions that, while related, are ultimately separate. Please ask them in separate posts, rather than asking them all in the same place.

Comment: The *least*-upper-bound of the set is $1$, but many numbers form *an* upper bound. Similarly, $0$ is the greatest lower bound.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I was pretty sure I understood your question, but I agree with @Aloizio: this is very unclear as to what you mean. I'm fairly sure you mean "as a subset of $\mathbb R$ with the euclidean metric, but I cannot be sure.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo, By lower bound, I mean there is an element where all elements in the set are either equal or greater to it. But I am not sure whether the elements has to exist in the set itself. Teacher did not mention that.

Comment: @Jake Are you studying analysis? If so, probably your professor meant what other people are telling: it is bounded as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

If not, then it is definitely unclear. We could be taking the space $A$ with its induced order from $\mathbb{R}$, in which there is no lower bound. This kind of issue is kind of relevant in topology, for example. One can have that the topology of the induced order on a subspace is not the induced topology of the order topology on the (big) space.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo, I am studying Mathematical Analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the greatest lower bound of $A$ is $0$. First, it’s clear that $0<\frac1n$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, so $0$ is *a* lower bound for $A$. Secondly, if $x>0$, then there is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\frac1n<x$, so $x$ is not a lower bound for $A$. Thus, $0$ must be the largest lower bound for $A$.

Any real number smaller than $0$ is also a lower bound for $A$, so $-2$ is indeed a lower bound for $A$. Similarly, any real number larger than $1$ is an upper bound for $A$, so $2$ is an upper bound for $A$.

The set $\Bbb Z^+$ is bounded below (by any $x\le 1$) but not above, and $\Bbb Z$ is not bounded at either end. You can probably easily come up with other examples.

Comment: So the lower/upper bound does not have to be in the set. Is that right?

Comment: @Jake: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: @Jake: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

*I am studying the following set
$$ A=\left\{\frac{1}{n},\;n\in \mathbb N\right\}$$
where $\mathbb N$ begins from $1$ not $0$. I know that the upper bound of this set is $1$ but what is the lower bound?*

***A* upper bound is $1$ and *a* lower bound is $0$, but there others.**

*Does the lower/upper bound have to exist in the set?*

**No. ("greatest/least element" have to exist in the set, but  "lower/upper bounds" and "supremum/infimum" don't.)**

*What I mean is can I pick for example $2$ to be the upper bound or $-2$ to be the lower bound?*

**Yes.**

Finally, is there an examples of (1) a set that is bounded from one end only and (2) an example of a set that is not bound from both ends?

**Yes:**

$$\{n,\;n\in\mathbb{N}\}\tag{1}$$
$$\{-n,\;n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{n,\;n\in\mathbb{N}\}\tag{2}$$